# JavaScript Bookmarklet Issue

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Ok so, I created a bookmarklet to open up a website and log in for me. I got it to work, but it only works if I hold `Ctrl` when I click the bookmark. can anyone help me fix the issue so that it will work even if I don't hold `Ctrl`?

```
window.location.assign("https://www.thewebsiteiwant.com");
window.onload=doThis;
function doThis(){
    document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value="username";
    document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value="password";
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i = 0;i < inputs.length; i++){
        if(inputs[i].type === "submit"){
            inputs[i].form.submit();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

and yes, I do know that saving my username/password in a bookmark is a huge security issue, but if a hacker got into my work computer, the last thing they'll go for is my login for a page containing un-useful information.

EDIT2:

GOT IT TO WORK, Thanks @DG for helping me brainstorm:

```
javascript:
var sitexyz = "https://www.thewebsiteiwant.com";
if(document.URL == sitexyz){
    document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value="username";
    document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value="password";
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i = 0;i < inputs.length; i++){
        if(inputs[i].type === "submit"){
            inputs[i].form.submit();
        }
    }
} else {
    window.location.assign(sitexyz);
    window.onload=doThis;
    function doThis(){
        document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value="username";
        document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value="password";
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var i = 0;i < inputs.length; i++){
            if(inputs[i].type === "submit"){
                inputs[i].form.submit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am astounded that you found a way to do this. I've never seen this technique before, and I am somewhat of a minor expert on bookmarklets (check my SO history). FYI, it works in Chrome, but seems to not work in Firefox. I seriously doubt you'll find a way to do it without using CTRL. This is a question that has been asked many times before and it is amazing to me that there is any work around at all. Be thankful you found even this.

Comment: Do you think that adding an if statement and having it check the current url and running a script based off of that would help? Then I could just click it a couple times

Comment: Yes, of course that should work. That is also an interesting approach.

Comment: got it working, thanks for helping me brainstorm DG :)

check my edit#2 if you want the code that I used.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I've cleaned up and made some right proper bookmarklet code for you ;)

```
// bookmarklet to open a page and login
// option 1: click once to open page, click again to login
// option 2: CTRL+click to open and login; Chrome only.

javascript:(function(w,d){
  var go = 'http://example.com',
    login = ['myUserName','myPass'],
    inpName = ['username','password'];
  function doit(){
    var un = d.getElementsByName(inpName[0]),
      pw = d.getElementsByName(inpName[1]);
    if (!(un && pw)) alert('login form not found!');
    else {
      un[0].value = login[0];
      pw[0].value = login[1];
      pw[0].form.submit();
    }
  }
  if (d.URL == go) doit();
  else {
    w.location.assign(go);
    w.onload = doit;
  }
})(window,document);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd usually think of js bookmarks as being formed like this:

```
javascript:document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value="username";...
```

…which you would be able to fire when you'd visited a page.  If window.onload was able to be set for loading a different url - then it would be quite a big security issue (as you'd be able to inject script into any other page).

As a more general solution to logging into a page, you're better to use a password manager (like the one that comes with Chrome, or lastPass etc).